# TypeError: The "original" argument must be of type Function - SASS

Tags: sass, dart-sass

I'm trying to use the `dart-sass` module to compile some SCSS in my React project with Typescript. I installed the module, imported it, and got the error in the title. What could it be? Some type of imports I tried:

```
import { renderSync } from 'sass';
import sass from 'sass';
const sass = require('sass');
```

Everything throws the following error:

> TypeError: The "original" argument must be of type Function - SASS

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow these steps i think it will fix your problem :

Add node-sass to your project

```
$ npm i node-sass --save-dev
```

Include node-sass in your Gruntfile

```
const sass = require('node-sass');
```

In your sass options, change the following line

from

```
implementation: 'sass-dist'
```

to

```
implementation: sass
```

Comment: I don't have a Gruntfile in the project neither will I need one. I'm using webpack that already comes with react.

Comment: The problem is, "node-sass" doesn't support apple M1 CPU architecture.

Comment: I ended up not pursuing this solution anyway, but thank you both for the heads up.